# Running pod install from Xcode cocoapods plugin

Tags: ios, ruby, rubygems, cocoapods, rbenv

I am trying to run a `pod install` command from the [Xcode cocoapods plugin](https://github.com/kattrali/cocoapods-xcode-plugin).

When I run the update/install cocoapods command I get an error:

```
/usr/bin/gem install cocoapods

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

It is strange as if I go to the directory in terminal and run a `pod install` I have no issues.

What is to note is that the error refers to Ruby 2.0.0, whilst when I run a `ruby -v` command from the directory in terminal I get `(ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0])`

EDIT - as requested:

```
ls -la /Library/Ruby/Gems  
total 0  
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  136 27 Oct 23:39 .  
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  136 27 Oct 23:36 ..  
drwxr-xr-x  6 root  wheel  204 25 Aug 02:44 1.8  
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel   68 25 Aug 04:13 2.0.0
```

Comment: please show the output of `ls -la /Library/Ruby/Gems`

Comment: try use `sudo /usr/bin/gem install cocoapods`

Comment: @p11y - question updated

Comment: @Luiz- I have completed your comment successfully and the same issue occurs. same permission error per question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was a permission error to the suggested path:

I run the following:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/"
```

Then had another error pointing to /usr/bin, so run:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` "/usr/bin"
```

Comment: sudo chown -R <YOUR_CURRENT_LOGIN_USER_NAME> "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/"

Answer (score 12):

This specific to Mavericks were the default Ruby has been upgraded to 2.0.0 and you have previously used CocoaPods with a previous version of Ruby. The workaround is to run the `gem install cocoapods` commands as `root`, but not as the logged in user with `sudo`.

From Terminal, run `sudo -s` to enter a shell as the `root` user. Then run `gem install cocoapods`. Now you can run `Run Update/Install` from the CocoaPods plugin.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but no luck. I run sudo -s, then gem install cocoapods, then Quit Xcode/restarted and same issue permission error per question.

Comment: Does not solve the Problem. Still the same Error-Message appears.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks for the tip + the explanation.